# Create a folder in dropbox from Iphone App

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am a beginner in iOS development and have just started using the DropBox SDK for iOS. I am using XCode 3.2.5 having the simulator 4.2 . I wanted to create a folder(or directory) on my dropbox account using the DropBox SDK programmatically and upload files directly to that folder in my DropBox account. I have the following code to upload a file

`[[self restClient] uploadFile:@"info.txt" toPath:@"/"  withParentRev:nil fromPath:sourceString];`

I have to store this file inside a folder called TempData(suppose). Then, I tried doing the following

`[[self restClient] uploadFile:@"info.txt" toPath:@"/TempData/"  withParentRev:nil fromPath:sourceString];`

but, it uploaded the file in the default directory for my App. Also, can I upload the contents of an entire directory in to my dropbox account. I have a lot of metadata files which need to be uploaded along with the uploaded files. So, is there a way to upload the entire contents of a folder to dropbox. I have looked up the API in DropBox SDK version 1.1 for iOS, but, it does not have any facility to upload an a directory or all of its contents recursively. So, Will I have to traverse recursively over the contents of a directory and send multiple requests? Please help

Answer (score 3):

This is used to create a Folder in DropBox

```
[[self restClient] createFolder:@"/YourFolder"];
```

This is Used to get details of the newly created folder

```
// Folder is the metadata for the newly created folder
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client createdFolder:(DBMetadata*)folder{
    NSLog(@"Created Folder Path %@",folder.path);
        NSLog(@"Created Folder name %@",folder.filename);
}
// [error userInfo] contains the root and path
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client createFolderFailedWithError:(NSError*)error{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

Comment: How to check if a folder is already available before creating it?

Comment: you can check that here in
**`- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {
    for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents) {
if(child.isDirectory && [child.filename isEqualToString:@"yourFolderName"]){
//you have that folder Already 
}else{
//No you dont have that folder
}
}
}`** @Satyamsvv