# Upload a folder to DropBox using iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, dropbox

I am beginner in iOS Development and have just started using the DropBox SDK for developing an App.

I am currently using XCode 3.2.5 and using the Simulator version 4.2. I wanted to know if there was any way by which we can directly upload the contents of an entire  folder(directory) containing n number of files to our App account using DropBox SDK for iPhone.

I went across the discussions in various forums across the net, but could not find an answer to solve this problem. Is there a possible work-around solution for this problem. If yes, how can we implement it? Can you please help.

EDIT: I have looked up the API in DropBox SDK version 1.1 for iOS, but, it does not have any facility to upload an a directory or all of its contents recursively. So, Will I have to traverse recursively over the contents of a directory and send multiple requests? Please help.

Comment: @Abizern Please go through the edited question. I am sorry, if my question was not properly formatted as I am new to StackOverflow as well, I will keep that thing in mind before asking questions. :)

Comment: @Abizern Yes, I have looked at the API and have used the API for uploading and downloading files to my application. The Problem is that I am sending a lot of meta data files with the files which are getting uploaded. So, that is why I wanted to know if there was a workaround solution to my question..

Comment: Possible duplicate of your own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986334/create-a-folder-in-dropbox-from-iphone-app. Please update the original question with any updated information rather than asking another one.

Answer (score 0):

Read And Use the Contents Within Following Link

http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2011/1/20/how-to-synchronize-your-app-data-using-dropbox-api.html

This Definatly helps You.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to accomplish this is like this:

```
NSFileManager *fmgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *localDirectoryPath = @"path/to/directory";
NSArray *subPaths = [fmgr subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:localDirectory error:&error];


for(NSString *path in subPaths){
        BOOL isDir;
        NSString *localPath = [userDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:path].path;
        [fmgr fileExistsAtPath:localPath isDirectory:&isDir];
        if(!isDir){
            NSString *filename = [path lastPathComponent];

            NSString *destPath = [[[@"/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"base/path"]
stringByAppendingPathComponent:path.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                                  stringByAppendingString:@"/"];

            [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destPath withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

click here:   https://github.com/chrishulbert/CHBgDropboxSync

for uploading & downloading dropbox folder/direcotry.