# Get folder structure of DropBox and create Folders and upload files in specific folders - iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am developing an application based on DropBox API. I am using [This](https://github.com/dropbox-sdk-mirror/dropbox-sdk-ios) code to implement DropBox API. Downloading is working fine. But I am new to DropBox API so it is quite difficult for me to create folders and upload files in a specific folder.

> I have mainly two functionalities are remaining to implement.
>
> 1 - Get complete folder hierarchy(Folder Structure) of DropBox Account.
>
> 2 - Upload PDF files into specific folders.

I have attached an image of what i want...

[image]

Please tell me the examples or demos for this...

Comment: do u want to create this type of app UI ?

Comment: I have created UI already. But i want to access folder structure from dropBox as per this UI.

Comment: DBMetaData has a property `BOOL isDirectory`, that will help you

Comment: Thanks Bala, but how can i create directory and how to upload files to a specific folder

Comment: [Create a folder in dropbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9892286/1059705) and give that specific path to that upload method

Comment: you can check if a folder exists already using this 
**`- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {
    for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents) {
if(child.isDirectory && [child.filename isEqualToString:@"yourFolderName"]){
//you have that folder Already 
}else{
//No you dont have that folder
}
}
}`** @NiravGadhiya

Comment: Nirav, have you figured this out? If so, maybe you can move @Bala's response to an answer and mark it. If not, what else do you need help with?

Comment: smarx, Thanks a lot for reply but I am satisfied with @Bala's reply. I have tried this and this is working fine.....

Comment: So shall i post those comments as answer ? @NiravGadhiya

Comment: @Bala : Sure you must make a answer from above comments to help other people who will read this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `DBMetaData` has a property `BOOL isDirectory` which helps you to check if it is a directory or not..
2. To create a folder in Dropbox,(which i have already answered here)[Create a folder in dropbox using DropBox Core Sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9892286/1059705)
3. check if a folder exists already using this

> ```
> - (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata 
> { 
>     for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents)
>     { 
>        if(child.isDirectory && [child.filename isEqualToString:@"yourFolderName"])
>        { 
>           // you have that folder Already 
>           // you can upload it here
>        }
>        else { 
>           // No you dont have that folder
>           // Create that folder here and upload 
>        }
>     }
>  }
> ```